# Prove equality powers of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Consider the following matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & A_{12} & A_{13} & A_{14} \\ 0 & 1 & A_{23} & A_{24} \\ 0&0&1& A_{34}\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Define $B=A^2, C=A^3, D=A^4$. Prove that
$$6B_{14}+D_{14}=4A_{14}+4C_{14}$$

My work so far:
I have realised that the characteristic polynomial for this matrix is $(1-\lambda)^4$. I have no clue how to move on, thank you for your explanation!

Comment: Try to calculate $B$, $C$ and $D$ to deduce $B_{14}$, $C_{14}$ and $D_{14}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Hamilton-Cayley, $(I-A)^4=0$ (since you have already found the char polynomial), so $I-4A+6A^2-4A^3+A^4=0$ or $4A+6C=4B+D+I$, now look at the $(1,4)$-entry and note that $I_{14}=0$.

Comment: Firstly, thanks! I have one more question: How do I know that 4+6=4+ holds for the (1, 4)-entry?

Comment: Because matrices add entry-wise.

Comment: ... so the $(1,4)$-entry of the sum of matrices is the sum of the $(1,4)$-entries of the summands.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Consider the $1,4$ entry of the matrix
$$
(6B + D) - (4A + 4C) = A^4 - 4A^3 + 6A^2 - 4 A 
\\ = [A^4 - 4A^3 + 6A^2 - 4 A + I] - I.
$$